# Disable full screen view in Google Play Books

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, google-play-books

On my 2013 Nexus 7, the Google Play Books app makes use of the new full screen feature in Android 4.4 KitKat to hide the system bars when the app is in use. This adds nothing useful to the experience, in my opinion, and requires annoying extra taps for trivial tasks like looking at the clock or switching apps. I can find no settings in the app for this. Is it possible to disable this "feature," preferably on a per-app basis?

Comment: Immersive mode is non user configurable I'm afraid. However, with a rooted device you could install the Xposed framework and 'Gravity Box Kitkat' and then you can add a toggle for Immersive Mode.

Comment: I HATE immersive mode... Going to switch to an iPhone I don't like being a gunnie pig and having my opeating system change fundamental functionality release after release.